# Create text file and add to zip file and download spring boot with out savind in local server

Tags: java, spring-boot, download, zip

create and download zip file by adding list of text files. with out creating the file in local server, it should be download at client side direct,
 Here i added a code snippet, it was creating in local server, but i dont want that, it should create and download at client side instant. Please help me in this way..

```
@GetMapping("/download/rawdata")
    public void downloadRawdata(@RequestParam("date") String date){

        log.info("date : "+date);
        List<Rawdata> rawdatas = rawdataRepoisotry.findRawdataByDate(date);
        log.info("size of rawdata : "+rawdatas.size());
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        int i = 1;
        for(Rawdata rawdata : rawdatas){
        log.info("rawdata : "+ rawdata.getRawdata());
            File file = new File(i+".txt");

            try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
                String contents = rawdata.getRawdata(); 
                writer.write(contents);
                files.add(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        try {
            zipFile(files, new File(date+".zip"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed while creating Zip file");
        }

    }


    public FileOutputStream zipFile(final List<File> files, final File targetZipFile) throws IOException {
        try {
          FileOutputStream   fos = new FileOutputStream(targetZipFile);
          ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
          for(File currentFile : files){
                if (!currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                  ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(currentFile.getName());
                  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
                  zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                  int read = 0;
                  while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                  }
                  zos.closeEntry();
                  fis.close();
                }
          }
          zos.close();
          fos.close();
          return fos;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("File not found : " + e);
          throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }


      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [FileSystemResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html).

What has been modified is (see the numbers in the commented code ) :

1) Declare that the response will be of type application/octet-stream

2) `@ResponseBody`

> Annotation that indicates a method return value should be bound to the
>   web response body

3) Declare that the method returns a `FileSystemResource` body

4) Return the `FileSystemResource` entity based on your created zip file

Note that this will still create the file on the server side first, but you may want to use [File.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [File.deleteOnExit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()).

```
    @GetMapping("/download/rawdata", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)//1
    @ResponseBody //2
    public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> downloadRawdata(@RequestParam("date") String date){ //3

        log.info("date : "+date);
        List<Rawdata> rawdatas = rawdataRepoisotry.findRawdataByDate(date);
        log.info("size of rawdata : "+rawdatas.size());
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        int i = 1;
        for(Rawdata rawdata : rawdatas){
        log.info("rawdata : "+ rawdata.getRawdata());
            File file = new File(i+".txt");

            try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
                String contents = rawdata.getRawdata(); 
                writer.write(contents);
                files.add(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        try {

            File resultFile = new File(date+".zip");
            zipFile(files, resultFile);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(new FileSystemResource(resultFile), HttpStatus.OK); //4

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed while creating Zip file");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your speed reply.. but i want to download directly at client side with out creating the folders at server side, please help me in that way

Comment: Is there any other way to download directly without creating at servers side

Comment: Well if you want to do everything in memory, you may want to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as a parameter to the `ZipOutputStream` , then return a `ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource>` that reads from the populated byte array (retrieved from  `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`).

Comment: Actually i dont want to create text files also at server side

Comment: anyone know the answer??